# Firebase fails to initialise on release build, Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Am new to flutter and was trying around Firebase, but the app doesn't initialize Firebase on release
it throws an error, yet it works wen you just run the app. Am using android studio

> ** E/flutter (12950): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method Firebase#initializeC ore on channel
> plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
>
> E/flutter (12950): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156) E/flutter
> (12950):  E/flutter (12950): #1
> MethodChannel.invokeListMethod
> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:344) E/flutter
> (12950):
>
> E/flutter (12950): #2      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore
> (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:30)
> E/flutter (12950):
>
> E/flutter (12950): #3      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp
> (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:75)
> E/flutter (12950):
>
> E/flutter (12950): #4      Firebase.initializeApp
> (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:44) E/flutter (12950):
>
> E/flutter (12950): #5      main
> (package:ug_campus_papers_example/main.dart:13) E/flutter (12950):
>  E/flutter (12950):
> **

Line 13 is the await Firebase.initializeApp();

My Main file is

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'App1 Test',
      home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
            return Make1(user: user,);
          } else
            return SignInScreen();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The pubspec.yaml file is as below

```
name: ug_camp_example
description: My Flutter app 1.

version: 3.0.1+3

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_storage: "^7.0.0"
  firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.16.0+1"
  ug_camp:
    path: ../

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts:
  provider:
  file_picker: ^1.1.1
  flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer:
  sqflite:
  path:
  flutterwave:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.4


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/images/apptest1.png"
  android: true
  ios: true

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: There's a similar exception in this SDK, you might wanna try the solutions: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3212#issuecomment-676585620

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

1. Update your firebase packages to the latest versions. You're very outdated.
2. Ensure you've added your google-services.json to the project.

You mentioned you are using Android Studio, although are you running on Android or iOS? I can provide more instructions depending on the platform.

Comment: am running on  Android